# The new elasticsearch-ruby gem integrating with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

there is any way to integrate the new Elasticsearch gem for ruby to rails, the tire was great but retired since two month and replaced by the new gem, however, no integrating functions with rails yet.

all the tutorial use tire, but now, how we can using rails with Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another gem called "searchkick" that integrates elasticsearch with Rails:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

It has some really cool features and can index data through rake tasks.

Comment: That looks nice. However, it should be noted, that this gem depends on (re)tire.

Answer (score 13):

A full-featured Rails integration is being worked on. If you want the high-level integration, and you don't want to provide it yourself, you can stick with Tire.

Comment: but tire is not maintaining now? it's will be easy to change from tire o the new gem in futur?

Comment: Tire is being maintained, see the documentation. The migration from Tire to the new gem will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

I have a minmimal implementation that I'm currently running for prototyping / evaluation of ElasticSearch, which has not thrown up any spanner in the works for a very focused prototyping run for the past 2 days ...

There's little or no error response checking yet, since our workloads heavily use Resque and we rely on Resque to capture and identify where we need to fine tune error handling.

https://gist.github.com/TobiG77/8610788