# elasticsearch-rails VS (re)tire gem (Elasticsearch and Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, elasticsearch, tire

I want to integrate [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org) with my Rails 3.2 app. I used [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire) before and it was perfect and straight forward, now it is retired based on its documentation

> NOTICE: This library has been renamed and retired in September 2013 (read the explanation). It is not considered compatible with Elasticsearch 1.x.

and it refers to the new [elasticsearch suite of gems](http://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails), but is it mature enough? has a community? tutorials and how tos? which led me to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704113/the-new-elasticsearch-ruby-gem-integrating-with-rails) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19704890) of [karmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95696/karmi) himself! Now I am confused, which gem to use?

We need a gem that is fully maintained and provides full implementation of elasticsearch features; as my project is a long term one and we will be exploiting the search engine heavily.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

The Elasticsearch suite of gems is developed and maintained by Elasticsearch as the official Ruby/Rails client. Please note that [karmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95696/karmi) is the developer of the new suite for Ruby. Please read the blog post - [release the clients! ruby, python, php, perl](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/unleash-the-clients-ruby-python-php-perl/) for more details.

**Some Highlights**

> Tire managed to solve many issues for a nice Ruby and Rails integration, and it also managed to make some seriously bad decisions. Today marks a fresh start for me, and for Ruby users of Elasticsearch. Today, we’re releasing a suite of clients with common design and semantics, which aims to provide a solid foundation for further extensions, integrations and experiments.
>
> ...
>
> If you liked Tire, you can be sure that all the convenience for painless Rails integration will come soon. If you hated Tire, I’d like to invite you to kick the tires on the new Ruby client. I took great care to avoid all the bad decisions of Tire, and make the library — or, in fact a collection of three libraries — as modular, extensible and robust as much as I could. Your feedback, opinions and critique — either via Github issues, via IRC or via e-mail — is most welcome!
>
> ...
>
> Because we wrote these clients and they are tested by us, we can provide official support for them. When bugs are found, we can fix them quickly – it’s our job.

Hope this helps.